# Newline character not being added to string

Tags: c#, string

This is my test code

```
public string myMethod(int[,] anArray)
{
    string aString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (j == anArray.Length - 1)
            {
                aString += " " + anArray[i, j] + "\r\n";
                continue;
            }
            aString += anArray[i, j] + "|";
        }
    }
    return aString; 
}
```

When I call the method, I'm expecting a string that has newline characters in it.

My desired result

```
0|0|0
0|0|0
0|0|0
```

However I get this

```
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Silly mistake on the if condition, nothing more.

**2nd EDIT:** I had the wrong if condition statement in the latter portion of my code, leading to an incorrect string.

Comment: Did you try it with `environment.newline()`

Comment: I don't think the line `aString += " " + anArray[i, j] + "\r\n";` is ever hit. Otherwise you'd also have spaces in your output, and you don't.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable that is inefficient.

```
StringBuild sb = new StringBuilder();
for ()
{
   sb.AppendLine(" " + anArray[i, j]);
}
```

As per the comment

```
anArray.GetLength(1) 
anArray.Length
```

Not the same

Answer (score 0):

`if (j == anArray.Length - 1)` replaced by `if (j == anArray.GetLength(1) - 1)`

```
public string myMethod(int[,] anArray)
{
    string aString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (j == anArray.GetLength(1) - 1)
            {
                aString += anArray[i, j] + "\r\n";
                continue;
            }
            aString += anArray[i, j] + "|";
        }
    }
    return aString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like this:

```
if (j == anArray.GetUpperBound(1))
{
    aString += anArray[i, j] + "\r\n";
    continue;
}
```